# Undefined property with class in php

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined property: Pub::$pub in I:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 37
NULL

I think i did anything right but i don't know why i have such problem? can someone tell me what i did wrong i will be thankful.

```
class Pub {

    function getip()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];

        foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP') as $key) 
        {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {

                foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {

                    if (validip($ip) !== false) {

                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function validip($ip)
    {
        return (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/", $ip)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

}

$pub = new Pub;

var_dump( $pub->getip);
```

Comment: `var_dump( $pub->pub );` there is no `pub` property defined in Class Pub

Comment: yes my mistake i edite my post sorry but same problem

Comment: you forgot to add `()` after the `getip`. It should be `$pub->getip()` instead of `$pub->getip`

Comment: Yes, you got it. Thank you. i'm such a inane :( any way thank you.

Comment: Also have a look at @TVs answer, he spotted one more error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property pub, you're probably referring to `$pub->getip()`.

That would require you to change this line:

```
if (validip($ip) !== false) {
```

to this:

```
if ($this->validip($ip) !== false) {
```

Seeing as it won't be able to find validip in that context.

[Read about the basics of OOP in PHP here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)